# How to set Data Set Values in Master Page Footer

Tags: birt

I am new to BIRT can you guys help me in this, my requirement is like, I have two fields PMNUM and CHANGEID, I need to show these two fields in master page footer based on third column value TYPE. If TYPE is PM I need to show PMNUM and if TYPE is CM I need to show CHANGEID.

---

I followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lw_k1qHY_gU&t=4s video to get PMNUM in the footer. But the problem here is if I hide PMNUM From the table, the PMNUM from the footer also hiding. Please guide me on how to solve this problem and share some guide for BIRT events.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some script inside your table and assign PNUM and CHANGEID to global variables.
In the page footer reference to the global variables instead of the table's values that in your case may be hidden.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your replay,  my question is how to assign PMNUM, CHANGEID to global variables. I tried like this way in Report initialize Event                                                                   reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("my",dataSetRow["PMNUM"]);
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("m1",this.getRowData().getColumnValue("PMNUM")); But both are not working for me.

Comment: The assignment must be done within an actual table row. Maybe your code is in the table's header or footer which could explain the wrong behavior.